# How to do paging on nmcli help?

Tags: rhel, less, nmcli

I'm watching online lectures on the `nmcli` utility (NetworkManager, Red Hat), and the instructor conveniently uses the package `bash-completion` to figure out what options are available after each argument.  The problem is, I cannot use `bash-completion` (why not? that's a different issue).  So instead, I've been trying to use `less`, like:

```
# nmcli con add help | less
```

but for some reason, `less` is not working as expected.  If I hit the b key or the spacebar, it just fills the screen with empty lines starting with ~; I cannot navigate the output as expected.
Why does `less` behave like that in this case? Any other options to make the help from `nmcli` readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `nmcli con add help` goes to standard error, bypassing standard output. Your `less` command is left paging an empty stream.

It should work the way you expect if you redirect stderr to stdout:

```
nmcli con add help 2>&1 | less
```

Comment: how did you know it was going to stderr?

Comment: @Katerl3s I guessed - then confirmed by redirecting `2>/dev/null`